# jQuery Mobile: Hide header/footer on orientation change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to able to hide the header/footer when the device orientation event is called (I'd also settle for changing their data-position="fixed" attribute to not-fixed)

I've tried:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){

            if(event.orientation == 'portrait') {
                //do something
            } 
            if (event.orientation == 'landscape') {
                $.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(false);
            }
    });
```

I've also used:

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.hide(true);
```

But neither seems to do the trick. Has this been removed from JQM 1.1?

Comment: This hasn't been disabled as far as i know. can you do a `console.log('whatever')` or add a `breakpoint` to check the orientation?

Comment: @Ogodwhy: I can confirm orientation events are being checked correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With css media queries it's very simple to hide elements depending on the device orientation:

```
/* portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* portrait-specific styles */
}

/* landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* landscape-specific styles */
}
```

here is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/bwzdr/show/

(be sure to open this link with your mobile device)

---

EDIT:

I improved the above sample with a javascript-based detection of the orientation (added to the css), theoretically you could pass anything after "case":

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
    var orientation="portrait";
    if(window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90) orientation = "landscape";

    $("#status").html(orientation);  

    switch(orientation){
      case 'portrait':
        // alert('portrait');
        $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(true);
        break;
      case 'landscape':
        // alert('landscape');        
        $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    };        
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/npZwx/)

Comment: I no longer have access to the project source code due to contractual restrictions, but this solution works in a test file.

Answer (score 0):

In JQM 1.1 the name of the function has been made all lower case.  The previous method is not longer supported.

Show:

```
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('show');
```

Hide:

```
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');
```

**[More info on the docs.](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-methods.html)**

Comment: I've tried this too, and its still not working. "$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');" is not firing.

Comment: Changing it to $.mobile.activePage.children("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide'); now fires, but the toolbar is still fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the name of your footer you could just simply do this in your orientation detect function.

```
yourfooter.hide();
```

which is the same as setting that div to style="display:none;"

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like :

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
    if (event.orientation == 'landscape' ) {
        $.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(false);
    } else {
        $.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(true);
    }
});
```